# Languages or Dialects Wherein Rain/Cloud and Tear/Cry are Cognates

Tags: etymology, list-of-languages, vocabulary, cognates

Are there any languages or dialects wherein

- at least one of the words for *rain*, *(rain)drop*, or *(rain)cloud* is a [cognate](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cognate) of at least one the terms for *tear(drop)* or *cry(ing)* ?
- **or** *(rain)clouds* are called *tear  clouds* or *cry(ing) clouds* ?
- **or** there is no distinction between *tear(drop)* and *raindrop* ?

> - <sub>*This question is **not** about [poetic license](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Artistic_license).*</sub>
> - <sub>*Trivial examples, such as the English* raindrop *and* teardrop *being both [compounds](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Compound_(linguistics)) of* drop, *are excluded.*</sub>

Comment: Irish _deoir_ primarily just means ‘drop’ (of any kind), but is used on its own to refer to both teardrops and raindrops (_deora a bhaint as X_ ‘reduce X to tears’; _deora anuas_ ‘leak’ [in a roof that it rains through, lit. ‘drops from above’]). You can specify _deoir bháistí/fhearthainne_ ‘drop of rain’ for raindrops, but I don’t think there’s a similar disambiguating form for tears. Would you count that?

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet: Is it the main or only word for *tear* ?

Comment: Only word, as far as I know. Focloir.ie also doesn’t give any other options, so at least the only common word for it. Actually, I think I have to revise my initial statement: ‘tear’ is probably the primary sense of _deoir_, and ‘drop’ (in various meanings) is secondary to that. There’s also _braon_, which has generic ‘drop’ as its primary sense (including raindrops), but _isn’t_ used for tears.

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet: As far as I can tell, there are two distinct words, one of which seems to be the main word for *tear(drop)*, and the other the main word for *(rain)drop*; if there would have been only one main word for expressing both concepts, that would definitely have been on topic.

Comment: Not quite. _Deoir_ and _braon_ are both used with qualifying nouns/adjectives for various different types of drops (_braon/deoir allais_ bead of sweat, _braon/deoir uisce_ drop of water, _braon/deoir b[h]áistí/f[h]earthainne_ raindrop, _braon/deoir drúchta_ dewdrop, etc.). Both can also be used in most of these senses with no qualifier, but with no qualifier, only _deoir_ is used for tears, and only _braon_ is used for drinks. So Irish essentially has a lexeme for ‘tear(drop)’ and one for ‘drop (of drink)’, but none for ‘raindrop’ – you use one of the others with a qualifier for that.